# Check if function returned an error in Haskell

Tags: haskell, try-catch

I want to create a function that returns `True` when a function throws any kind of exception and `False` if it doesn't.

But I haven't been able to figure out a way to do this with the `catch` method at `Control.Exception`.

I want to catch the error thrown by `[1,2] !! 3` but also custom errors thrown by the usage of `error "Error msg"`.

Comment: A function itself does not raise an error, as in `[1,2] !! 3` does *not* raise an error. It is the evaluation, since Haskell is lazy, it is thus perfectly possible that such expression will never yield an error.

Comment: Show what you tried with catch, that's a workable solution but you probably mis-used it somehow.

Comment: The sort of "exception" thrown by `!!` is very different than exceptions thrown in a language like Java, and isn't really intended to be caught. The right answer in Haskell is to check that the index is in bounds *first* or, even better, restructure your algorithm to not use `!!` at all (which is easier than it sounds when you get used to the language).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use `catch` as follows:

```
example :: IO ()
example = do
   let handler :: SomeException -> IO Bool
       handler e = do
          putStrLn "Exception caught:"
          print e
          return False
   res <- (evaluate ([1,2::Int] !! 3) >> return True) `catch` handler
   print res
```

The last `print` will print `True` on normal termination, and `False` on exceptional termination.

The output messages in the handler can be removed -- they're only for illustration.

You can replace `SomeException` with any more specific exception type, if you only want to catch some of them.

Note that you can't catch exceptions outside IO, which makes them more limited. For that reason partial functions like `!!` should be avoided, preferring functions returning a `Maybe a` type instead, whose output can be checked anywhere.

Comment: Thanks, my problem was that I wasn't inside IO